Calm and Insight is the Normative Meditative Practice in Buddhism
Schools that reject meditation entirely are excluded, for obvious reasons.
Samatha/Vipassana, Calm/Insight, Stopping/Seeing are ubiquitous in all Sri Lankan, Indian, Tibetan, Chinese, Korean, Vietnamese, and Japanese Buddhism. Yet it becomes disfavored in the later dispensations of Pure Land Buddhism, even though the foundational teachers of Tien Tai cite it:

(Paul Swanson) "I recall that many years ago, at a time of youthful indiscretion, having a naïve and simplistic impression of the Mo-ho chih-kuan, a text which, from its title, implies that it is mainly about the meditational practice of “cessation and contemplation” (止 観, śamatha-vipaśyanā)."

Why then is it later dropped?
And why do most Buddhist teachers not know that everyone is doing it? So often it is insinuated that each school of practice has exclusivity, when it is literally inclusive to the extreme.

We live in a degenerate age (Mappo). The meditative practices of Samatha and Vipassana were considered ineffective ,difficult and self-reliant in this age.
Pure land Buddhists favoured practices in which others were involved like Amitabha Buddha. The new practice was called Nembutsu. In this practice they chanted Amitabh Buddhas name. This practice was of devotion , inclusivity and ease. Once we reach Pure land , it was easy to attain Nibbana.

I think most people focus on certain teachings, rather than trying to devote equal time to everything, and that also goes for people within the same tradition. Because there are a lot of different practices and teachings, and you can only do so many things at one time.
I gather that a main preoccupation of Pure Land followers is reciting certain names or phrases as many times as they can throughout the day, which they call nianfo or nembutsu. Practicing with a mantra develops mindfulness and concentration, as with other kinds of meditation object. Also, Buddhanussati or recollection of the Buddha is included in the 40 classic meditation objects. This actually even says "nianfo" is a translation of Buddhanussati, which surprised me.

In the Pali Nikayas, buddhānussaṭi is a practice which is said to lead all the way to nirvana:
“One thing, mendicants, when developed and cultivated, leads solely to disillusionment, dispassion, cessation, peace, insight, awakening, and extinguishment. What one thing? Recollection of the Buddha. This one thing, when developed and cultivated, leads solely to disillusionment, dispassion, cessation, peace, insight, awakening, and extinguishment [nirvana].” — AN 1.296


Obviously the mental defilements of most Buddhists show samatha-vipassana is not actually being developed by most Buddhists. For example, the suttas (AN 2.31) say when samatha is developed, lust is abandoned. Are we claiming it is normative that most Buddhists are free from lust?

What is the benefit of developing serenity?
Samatho, bhikkhave, bhāvito kamatthamanubhoti?
Lust is given up.
Yo rāgo so pahīyati.
What is the benefit of developing insight?
Vipassanā, bhikkhave, bhāvitā kamatthamanubhoti?
Ignorance is given up.
Yā avijjā sā pahīya
AN 2.31

Sitting cross-legged in meditation does not actually mean a practitioner is ending the mental defilements with actual samatha-vipassana.

Thank you! The egotism of self-structures makes it difficult for most people to understand it is their own behaviour, hindrances, defilements that lead them into harmful relationships with others, the world around them, and ultimately their own spiritual path. I try to point out the jhana factors as they arise. Serenity, rapture, equanimity, turning the senses "inward" rather than outward. My fear is that they might see this as a reward to fixate on, which seems unfortunate. It beomes striving, grasping once again. Any thoughts, Dhamma Dhatu?

Samatha/Vipassana is the heart of Buddhism. But they are harder to practice meaningfully.
So, some modern teachers drop them and use other techniques that are easy to practice for newly joined people. They do it to make Buddhism more famous among normal people. Because these practices are easy to follow by normal people / lay people.
But anyone who like to attain Nirvana in this life or like to go to core of Buddhism, must do Samatha/Vipassana. (at least Vipassana, Samatha is not necessarily a Buddhist teaching).
